# Can we use javascript in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to use Javascript functionality in c#.
Is it possible to use Javascript in c#? If yes how?

Can anyone provide me some guide or sample code?

Thanx

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "use javascript functionality in C#"? (i.e. I need to add scripting to my application)

Comment: Do you mean us javascript client side in an .aspx page, or execute javascript on the server/desktop from C#?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "How can I use Javascript as a .Net language?"?

Answer (score 1):

For executing a javascript function on page load use,

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "jsstring", "urfunction()", true);`

For executing on a button click event use,

`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(urbuttonId, typeof(button), "jsstring", "urfuction()", true);`

Answer (score 0):

http://odetocode.com/code/80.aspx shows a simple dynamic JScript eval which can be called from C#, whether this is what you are looking for I am not 100% sure.

Comment: just a note: jscript and javascript are two different beasts.

Comment: No they are not, they are just variants on ECMAScript and normally when people ask for running 'javascript' in a windows technology they are really referring to JScript. And in my experience people tend to confuse javascript with what ever the web browser actually implements, as from what I can tell the majority of differences between JScript and Javascript are related to scoping and how DOM interaction occurs, which is all about the web browser not the language.

Comment: While JScript and Javascript are very closely related, JScript.NET is indeed a different beast. Alan is presumably referring to the fact that the article is talking about JScript.NET and not JScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can send JavaScript to the page in a number of methods.

1) You can put a literal control on your page and set the value to a script.
2) Use the ASP.NET scriptmanager to [registerstartupscript](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider).

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly useless but the JVM(Java Virtual Machine) has [rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) a JavaScript engine.
This is only mostly useless as [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) is a Java implementation for .net including

> ```
> * A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
> * A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
> * Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability
> ```

allows you to use JavaScript in a very roundabout way as seen
here:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EmbeddingJSCS.aspx

also [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't invoke a function written in Javascript in C#.

You can, of course write C# inside an ASPX page that can invoke a Javascript function *on the client page* which is probably not what you are trying to do.

You can try to use JSC (jscript compiler) to compile your javascript code into a library which can then be referenced by .NET. However, jscript and javascript syntax differ, and you will more than likely be stuck having to make changes.

I ran into this problem several months ago. My solution was to port my javascript code to C# and use that.

Using the built in javascript debugging tools inside IE makes it pretty easy to do.